# WeakHashMap hashing by identity?

Tags: java, hash, weak-references, weakhashmap

I don't understand, why does [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) hashes keys by their `hashCode()` and identifies by `equals()`?

By contract of this class, it can used to tie any instance to any other instance. From my opinion, this implies hashing and comparing by identity.

Event in the doc there is a note about confusing usage with such class as `String`:

> This class will work perfectly well with key objects whose equals
>   methods are not based upon object identity, such as String instances.
>   With such recreatable key objects, however, the automatic removal of
>   WeakHashMap entries whose keys have been discarded may prove to be
>   confusing.

So, is there any implementation of this class, in some collections library, where it is hashed by identity?

Comment: There's `IdentityHashMap`, but it's not weak.

Comment: Yes true, it is not weak

Comment: Why do you need a weak identitymap? Is your use case special, or were you just confused by the documentation? `HashMap` allows you to use anything as keys/values, and it doesn't use identity either.

Comment: Suppose I need to add runtime field to `ArrayList<>`. I would create `WeakHashMap<ArrayList<>,MyFieldType>` and access it from there. These fields were automatically disappear along with `ArrayList<>` instances. Unfortunately, `hashCode()` of list calculates hash based on all list elements, `WeakHashMap` utilizes namely it, and `WeakHashMap#hash()` is made `final`. I regard is as bad design.

Comment: In other words, please suppose your own usecase of `WeakHashMap`, where keys should be compared by content.

Comment: I'm not sure I still understand your usecase, but having a `Collection` as a key would be bad for the hashing. However the "add runtime field to ArrayList" sounds a bit dubious too, design wise.

Comment: What other goals (than that dubious one) `WeakHashMap` can achieve?

Comment: Well it's a popular choice for caches. This is the first time I've ever heard of anyone adding fields to `ArrayList` at runtime. Sounds like some funky design.

Comment: I don't see how this is good for caching. Weak values would be better for caching, not weak keys. If you don't like adding field to `List` then regard adding field to a `Thread`.

Comment: It does require trickery (and keys with reference equality), and looks like I omitted the "home-grown" part (you wouldn't use a self-made cache in real work, would you?). However I'm much more intrigued by your "add fields to JDK classes during runtime" concept.